# cooking Nan bread

Tags: indian-cuisine

I don't have space for any more kitchen equipment, or money to waste. I want to cook nan breads but I don't have a tawa ( a sort of skillet) I do have a metal bakers peel that I use to put pizzaz in and out of the oven. can I cook on the gas stove using the peel instead of a tawa?

Comment: Don't you need a tandoor to make naan? From what I've seen, restaurants that don't have a tandoor serve chapati rather than naan.

Comment: @ThePhoton I frequently make naan on my outdoor grill.  Cooking over the coals and directly on the cooking grate.  While the appearance is slightly different from naan cooked in a tandoor, the flavor and texture is equivalent.  So...lack of a tandoor is not a deal breaker.

Comment: @moscafj, okay, but trying to do it on a tava (or similar surface) would still be barking up the wrong tree, then, right?

Comment: @ThePhoton Naan needs high heat for the fast cooking time and char.  I guess it depends on how hot you can get it, without destroying the tava.

Comment: An Indian friend in the UK cooked individual naans by holding them over the gas flame in tongs (one at a time). They were almost in the flames.  It worked very well indeed

Answer (score 1):

I LOVE naan! But I’ve only made it once. I used a cast iron skillet. As I understand it, naan needs high heat to cook quickly and develop the bread’s texture. Cooking them on a stovetop is a great way to go, but make sure you’ve done your prep and your kitchen’s well ventilated.

As for the pizza peel, if it can handle high heat for longer than it takes to put a pizza in the oven, I see no reason why you couldn’t use it, although if you do have a cast iron skillet, I’d recommend that, for its heat retention and stability on a burner.

Good luck!